# Seeing a lot of logs in auth.log that concerns me

Tags: ssh, passwords, authentication

So I enabled publickey,password, as well as 2FA device for authentication to connect through SSH into my computer.
However, I am seeing many many entries per minute below:

```
error: Disabled method "password" in AuthenticationMethods list "publickey,password"
Authentication methods list "publickey,password" contains disabled method, skipping [preauth]
Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port xxx:xx [preauth]
```

This concerns me as there seems to be a forced disabling of authentication. 
Should this be of concern for me?

Comment: You have specifically disallowed password authentication but later in your configuration indicate it should be considered.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hello Ramhound, the issue is it wasn't me who Disabled method "password". So I am asking who did this? And do the logs mean my computer system has been compromised?

Comment: Provide the contents of appropriate configuration file.

Comment: Which configuration file should I look at ?

Comment: You need not be concerned about the security of thus setup if it's working OK - SSH is advising you that it is PREVENTING some logins, not allowing them.

Comment: File to post is /etc/ssh/sshd.conf

Comment: @davidgo Hello David, So it means that someone was trying to only use password to login when there needs to publickey and password needed right?

Comment: Sort of. We don't know what they were doing from the logs, only that they did not succeed.  As an aside, I could be wrong but I don't think SSH handles key+password logins. A key login is typically protected by a passphrase on the key (ie it encrypts the key), but that is at the discression of the key owner and not something SSH can check as it is only presented the unencrypted version- the owner can change or remove passphrase without interaction with the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** These logs are merely informational; `sshd` is telling you that it's *preventing* connection attempts.

Whenever someone first brings a server with SSH to the open internet, it's common for them to marvel at the sheer number of connection attempts made. The fact is that there are hundreds of thousands of bots scanning pretty much the entire open IPv4 space and attempting SSH login with common credentials.

There is no escaping and unfortunately it's rather normal. Make sure you disable password authentication and keep your private keys secure.

Answer (score -2):

Add this after the UsePAM yes

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: It solves the issue with the above. I solve problems, not wasting time for bullshits.

Comment: OP isn't asking how to configure their system. They're asking what these messages mean and if they should be concerned. Your answer doesn't address these questions. Moreover, OP apparently exposes their SSH server on a public IPv4 address. I'd argue a complete answer should discuss the risks of password authentication in this situation, rather than encourage enabling it. That's not "bullshit", it's working with them towards their goal of setting up this server securely.

Comment: Do you know what this command is doing in sshd_config? Of course not. The guy does not understand how to set up RSA key with passphrase and for example Google Authenticator as second way of securing the logon process. He sees the error, because every single tutorial about the Google Authentication for Linux ssh contains wrong piece of code or entry rather. This is the correct. Most people do not understand what they are doing, but just copy paste is their method. So the whole above comment is a nonsense, because securing ssh with RSA and Google Authentication is obvious.

Comment: He did not expose the system. If you add a public IP to DNS and configure your server with bind for example, or you buy a VPS with public IP you are exposed already just like that.

Comment: This is not a kindergarten. Buy good books, learn RHCSA, learn how to read logs, what they mean. My solution get rids of this error, because it is complaining about improper configuration in sshd_config.